# operation is not valid due to current state of object in Unity 3d

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and practicing transform movements on camera. The code for the c# script that I am applying on it is.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class HelloWorld : MonoBehaviour {


    public float speed = 2f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame 
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(speed,0,transform.position.z) * Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

but the console is showing errors stating:
[image]

I searched for the problems and managed to get that the debugger is unable to get any thing from top of stack. But i am unable to figure out how its related to particular code and where actual problem exist?

**Error Log:**
*solution->Open( bstrSolution )m_CurrentEntriesPtr == NULL || !m_IsGettingEntries
UnityEditorInternal.LogEntries:GetEntryInternal(Int32, LogEntry)
UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow:OnGUI() (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\ConsoleWindow.cs:454)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String, Object) (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:241)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String) (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:234)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI() (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:671)
[C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor/Src/EditorMonoConsole.h line 90] 
(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Editor/Mono/ConsoleWindow.cs Line: 454)
m_CurrentEntriesPtr == NULL || !m_IsGettingEntries
UnityEditorInternal.LogEntries:GetEntryInternal(Int32, LogEntry)
UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow:OnGUI() (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\ConsoleWindow.cs:458)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String, Object) (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:241)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String) (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:234)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI() (at C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\DockArea.cs:671)
[C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor/Src/EditorMonoConsole.h line 90] 
(Filename: C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Editor/Mono/ConsoleWindow.cs Line: 458)
InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
  at System.Collections.Stack.Peek () [0x0000c] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Stack.cs:321 
  at UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.EndLayoutGroup () [0x0001b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\artifacts\EditorGenerated\GUILayoutUtility.cs:223 
  at UnityEditor.SplitterGUILayout.EndVerticalSplit () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\GUI\Splitter.cs:491 
  at UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow.OnGUI () [0x00761] in C:\BuildAgent\work\d63dfc6385190b60\Editor\Mono\ConsoleWindow.cs:488 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000d0] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222*

Comment: 1) you can select, copy and paste the log info as text. Screenshots are hard to read. 2) Did you double-click the highlighted line? It should open Mono and show the line where the issue originated. Post that line plus surrounding lines for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: if you explain what you want to do i tell you but for example transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: thanks bro, I want to move camera along x axis. I have placed a cube as well but by applying Vector3.forward it stays still and get out of scene after few seconds.

Comment: transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: You probably want `Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime`. @user A multiplication with a Vector3 also creates new Objects! (Structs in this particular case)